# Badge tracker not showing progress toward "Legendary"

Tags: bug, reputation, badges, badge-progress

Despite gaining at least 200 rep each day today and yesterday, the badge tracker has been stuck at showing only 86 days of progress towards the Legendary badge. This might have something to do with half of that rep coming from a Documentation edit, but if I hadn't made that edit, I still would have gotten enough rep from answer upvotes to hit 200 today.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering why they didn't get progress towards Legendary, I had read on meta that doc rep apparently doesn't contribute to Legendary. But in your case, it sounds like a bug possibly related to your 200 rep not solely being Q/A rep (even though you had enough Q/A rep in itself to cap).

Comment: @PetahChristian: It usually updates in under a minute, IIRC. I didn't technically get enough Q/A rep to qualify for progress, but only because I hit the cap on a Doc-Q/A rep mix and further Q/A upvotes stopped counting.